# Kops - change images to use new gcr repo registry.k8s.io

Tags: kubernetes, kops

kops https://github.com/kubernetes/kops uses the deprecated image registry at k8s.gcr.io.

How do I change the image registry to use private locations?

Not all image locations are specified in cluster.spec.  I can see some in the add-ons folders but updating these files directly in S3 does not work - kops immediately reverts the changes on cluster update.

**Questions**

- How do I change the image registry for kops deployments?
- How do I change the image registry for add-ons such as dns-controller?

Many Thanks